# I'm a newbie using rails. I want to make my rails app file be editable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie using rails. I want to make my app/views/themes/index.html.erb be editable thru the browser. Anyone here have an idea how to do it?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but that also sounds *really bad*, because it would allow server-side code injections. It would also require that the server process could write to said file. Anyway, what about WebDAV or similar for such tasks?

Comment: I'm about to implement it inside the CMS, This is for my cms template feature

Comment: In my view, a "CMS" should be designed around content *within* the framework, but not necessarily the framework itself. Of course there are some mature "CMS" systems that allow providing custom pages (e.g. Site Pages in SharePoint) and also have well-integrated security precautions and restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

As a video tutorial is better than I could ever explain, check those 2 links

http://railscasts.com/episodes/332-refinery-cms-basics

http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor

Will explain you how to easily set a WYSWYG editor for your HTML content (not your ruby code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-place editing gem.. Here is the link
 http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ckeditor` to achieve this. See these posts.
http://ckeditor.com/demo

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor